# How Best to Keep Function From Closing File?

Tags: c++, file-io, stl, constants

So, I've been trying to be more rigorous with making any passed parameters that shouldn't be touched by a function `const`.

One situation I've encountered in some of my C++ code is the case where the object may change, but where I want to "lock out" functions from access certain key functionality of the object.  For example, for an `std::ifstream` file handle, I may wish to prevent the function from closing the file.

If I pass it as a `const &`, the `const` part keeps me from performing standard file i/o, it seems.

e.g. I want something along the lines of

```
void GetTags(Arr<std::string> & tags, std::ifstream const& fileHandle)
```

...but written in such a way to allow file i/o but not open/close operations.

Is there any good/reliable way to do this in C++?  What would be considered best practice?

Comment: At some point you need to accept that the users of your code are grown-ups who can be trusted to use it properly. Things like `const` are a handy tool but they don't solve every potential problem.

Comment: True, but I think making constant values `const` just makes sense and improves readability, as well as reducing inadvertent errors from contributors.  See Kerrek SB's solution... it makes a lot more sense to pass the stream than the handle.  Just as it makes more sense to pass a `const unsigned int` for a constant value versus a vanilla `unsigned int` param that you're treating as a constant without letting the reader know that explicitly...

Comment: By all means use whatever facilities you can to make the code safer and/or easier to reason about. I'm glad this particular problem had a good solution. I'm just warning you there's a limit to this line of thought - if you had to make a wrapper to remove some functions for example I don't think it would be worth it.

Comment: I see, gotcha, I agree with that certainly!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has already been done for you by the standard library design: Pass a reference to the *base* class `std::istream` instead, which does not have a notion of opening or closing - it exposes *only* the stream interface.

```
void stream_me(std::istream & is);

std::ifstream is("myfile.txt");
stream_me(is);
```

Comment: Ah perfect, that makes sense.  I was thinking this seems like functionality that would be baked in to the template library.  Better a standardized solution than a wrapper object/child.

Answer (score 1):

In your place I'd just pass a `std::istream` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the ifstream in an object that only exposed the functionality that you wished the caller to be able to use.

However, if you have a bunch of different functions, each with a different subset of ifstream's functionality, you'll end up with lots of different wrapper classes; so I don't see this as a general solution.

Comment: True, but if you look at the `iftream` spec: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/ ... there really are only two types of things you would be doing with it -- opening/closing the handle, or performing various read related duties on it.  Thus I don't see why it would make sense to make more than the wrapper I outlined above.  I'm open to that answer, but I'd want to get some insight into how to do it...

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to wrap the `ifstream` in a new class which only has member functions corresponding to the functionality you want`GetTags` to have access to.  Then pass that not the `ifstream` as the second argument to `GetTags`.

Comment: Is there a way to exclude certain functions.  e.g. basically I want to keep all the functions besides Open and Close.  Would I just create a child class of `ifstream` with those two functions overrided with a la `void open ( const char * filename, ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in ) {}` ??

Comment: NVM, see Kerrek SB's solution for a standardized answer for only accessing the stream portion...

Comment: @JasonR.Mick Yes his looks like the way to go, +1 to him.